# Adding a month to a date. Setting day to last day of given month

Tags: php, postgresql, date

I am trying to add a month to a date in posgresql, while setting DAY to the last day of the month.
How?

**An example**

```
UPDATE temp 
SET expiration_date = expiration_date + interval '1' month
WHERE name = 'xxx'
```

The thing is, that if date was 2014-04-30 for example, it will add one month, and date will become 2014-05-30, and May does have 31 days.

**Examples of what i want to accomplish**
2014-04-30 + 1 month -> 2014-05-31
2014-05-31 + 1 month -> 2014-06-30

Need some tips on that. Is it possible in postgres? I could use PHP to count it, but I would love to avoid that.

Comment: try :   update temp set CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 month' where name='xxx';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want a last day of the following month. This can be done like this:

```
SELECT date_trunc('mon','2014-04-30'::date+interval'2mon')-interval'1day',
       date_trunc('mon','2014-05-31'::date+interval'2mon')-interval'1day';
```

Comment: Love the answer. Yes, you understood right. That was what i wanted. Working like a charm!